# Some Questions on PHP execution?

Tags: java, php, zend-framework

I am new to PHP . I have primarily worked on java. I want to run the helloworld program for PHP.  I got it how to do it through
[blog](http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/how-to-run-php-on-ubuntu/)

But I have got some basic questions :-

1. Do I need to install both Apache and PHP separately or there is a way where Apache come bundled with PHP ? On google , I see to install LAMP but not just
   Apache bundled with PHP .
2. Also in the mentioned blog, instruction did not to Apache where PHP is installed ? How it will know where PHP engine is ?
3. Can I run PHP program without webserver something from CLI with execution Engine like Zend (like in java with JDK)?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

1. If you are on Linux, I guess you need to install Apache, PHP separately by yourself (using those apt-get commands)
2. After you have installed Apache, it will search for PHP via the httpd.conf file by default.
3. Yes, if you want to run PHP as a script, you can run it in a terminal like /path/to/php somePhpFile.php

Comment: For poin 2, As you said `After you have installed Apache, it will search for PHP via the httpd.conf file by default.` , but in referred blog I did not see where they mentioned the path of installed php  under https.conf file ?

Comment: Yes, there should be a line saying LoadModule php7_module /path/to/php/module